# Apply qtip(jQuery plugin) to newly loaded items on page

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, plugins, qtip

Firstly, this is qtip, a jQuery plugin: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/ Basically it makes pretty tooltips.

I am using qtip on a mysql database result page, and the qtips work perfectly fine when I first load the page. However, I have sorting links on my page that cause the information inside a div to completely change (uses AJAX to put new info into the div by making a new mysql query that resorts the data and puts it in a table to replace the table on the page). When I click my sorting buttons, everything works except the qtips disappear. I use the qtips on the image captions (the "title"), so when I rollover the images on the sorted table, it's back to the normal tooltip.

I believe what is wrong is that the $(document).ready means that the qtip stuff will only load on the first page load, therefore when I change the table, all the qtips disappear. I found a topic on the qtip forum that seems to be related to my problem (http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-solved-reload-qtip-with-new-items) and I tried everything in that topic, and I am on the latest version of qtip so I used on() instead of live() because live() is deprecated. It still didn't fix it. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('img[title]').on('mouseover', function() { 
        if( typeof( $(this).data('qtip') ) == 'object' ){ return; }
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: false
            },
            style: 'cream',
            position: {
                viewport: $(window)
            }
        });
        $(this).qtip('show');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: are you doing a postback to sort sql results? therefore firing document.ready again? if not you probably have to assign the 'this.qtip' again after the sorting

Comment: I've never heard of a postback, but I'll look into it.

Comment: show the code that sorts results

Comment: I tried googling "mysql postback" and got no results. I guess it doesn't exist for mysql or is not very easy to do. This is pretty much the code I have for sorting: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By storing the qTip settings, it will be easy to (re)initilise qTip with the same settings after new content has been loaded.

Without full sight of your javascript, I can't be specific but something like this should do it :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var qtipOptions = {
        content: { text: false },
        style: 'cream',
        position: { viewport: $(window) }
    };

    $('img[title]').qTip(qtipOptions);

    $("#myButton").on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            //...
            //...
            //...
            success(function(html){
                $("#mySelector").html(html);
                $('img[title]').qtip('destroy').qtip(qtipOptions);
            })
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I would fit my code into yours. I'm not using ajax inside the qtip, but rather I'm using this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp So when I click on the sort links, it makes a call to another page that queries the database and creates a table that replaces the one on the page. I tried putting
<script type="text/javascript">
 var qtipOptions = { //options };
 $('img[title]').qtip('destroy').qtip(qtipOptions);
</script> at the end of the page that is called, didn't work. But maybe I'm not writing the code correctly; I'm kind of new to jQuery.

Comment: The w3schools reference shows you how to do raw AJAX but with jQuery on the page then it's folly not to use its AJAX capability. Learning `jQuery.ajax()` (and various shortcut methods) will be a great investment for  productivity now and in the future. Read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) through then go back to my suggested code. You will see that it's not "ajax inside the qtip" but "qtip inside ajax" - more completely, a `.qtip(...)` statement appears in the AJAX success handler.

Comment: I read up on that documentation and converted my code into jQuery AJAX and it finally works! :) Thanks. And you are right, that is definitely really useful in the future.